# How to copy or reproduce the menu background gradient onto a bitmap using the Windows API?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, menubar

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to copy/reproduce the background gradient of a Windows menu bar onto a bitmap.

In the IconToBitmap function below, the FillRect (wishfully) uses the GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU) in an attempt have it paint the menu background the way it is in Windows (unsurprisingly, the brush isn't a gradient but, it was worth a try.)

The BitBlt below it is an attempt to "cheat".  Grab a portion of the already painted menu bar and use that.  That didn't work either and I suspect the reason may be because the function IconToBitmap is called during the WM_CREATE of the main window (I'm not sure the menu bar exists that early in the window creation.)  I do need the background before the window is first made visible, that's the reason the function is called when processing WM_CREATE (but any other way that works before the window is visible is perfect.)

At this point, I'm out of ideas.

If someone knows how to either grab that menu background or reproduce it on a bitmap, that would be great.

Thank you.

PS: hardcoded values in the function will be removed in the final working version (hopefully, there will be one.)  Also, for Delphi, the datatype ptrint has to be changed to NativeInt.

```
function IconToBitmap(Wnd : HWND; Icon : HICON) : HBITMAP;
var
  Bitmap      : HBITMAP;
  BitmapDc    : HDC;
  BitmapRect  : TRECT;

  OldBitmap   : HBITMAP;

  dc          : HDC;

  MenuHeight  : ptrint;
  MenuY       : ptrint;

  WindowDc    : HDC;

begin
  Bitmap      := 0;
  BitmapDc    := 0;
  OldBitmap   := 0;
  dc          := 0;

  MenuY       := 0;
  MenuHeight  := 0;

  WindowDc    := 0;


  MenuY       := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME) +
                 GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);
  MenuHeight  := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUSIZE);

  WindowDc    := GetWindowDC(Wnd);


  dc          := GetDC(0);
  BitmapDc    := CreateCompatibleDC(dc);

  Bitmap      := CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, 16, 16);
  OldBitmap   := SelectObject(BitmapDc, Bitmap);

  with BitmapRect do
  begin
    Left      := 0;
    Top       := 0;
    Right     := 16;
    Bottom    := 16;
  end;

  FillRect(BitmapDc, BitmapRect, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU));
  BitBlt(BitmapDc, 0, 0, 16, 16, WindowDc, 20, MenuY, SRCCOPY);

  DrawIconEx(BitmapDc,
             0,
             0,
             Icon,
             16,
             16,
             0,
             0,
             DI_NORMAL);

  SelectObject(BitmapDc, OldBitmap);
  DeleteDC(BitmapDc);
  ReleaseDC(0, dc);

  IconToBitmap := Bitmap;
end;
```

Comment: What gradient are you talking about exactly?  The old Aero glass effect? or the effect used on toolbars?

Comment: The gradient that is the menubar background.  Of course, it changes depending on the theme and, generally speaking, user preference but, whatever it may be, I want to either reproduce that background or make a copy of it in a bitmap.  To see what I am talking about, start notepad, whatever menubar background appears for Notepad, that's the background I either want to copy or reproduce.

Comment: @AlexK.: OP is probably using Windows 7 (or earlier), where the menu bar indeed has a gradient background. See, for instance, https://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/pix/screenshots/rte31/rtemainsimple.png. Of course, in Windows 10, the menu bar background is a solid colour.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using Windows 7 but, I want to grab/copy whatever background is currently in use.  That's very important.  That's why  I tried to "cheat" and simply bitblt part of the menubar background onto a bitmap.  That seems the simplest way to get a a "strip" of the background.  I know I can get it if I do the bitblt while processing a WM_PAINT but I need it earlier than that.  Ideally during WM_CREATE but anytime before the window is visible would work.

Comment: DrawThemeBackground() & friends may be worth looking at.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the menu bar exists early or not, you can't blit what you don't see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [visual styles API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/uxctl-ref) to draw theme parts. Below example paints a menu bar background in the top of the client area of a form. You can adapt it to draw onto a bitmap canvas.

```
uses
  uxtheme, types;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Theme: HTHEME;
  Size: TSize;
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  Theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, VSCLASS_MENU);
  GetThemePartSize(Theme, Canvas.Handle, MENU_BARBACKGROUND, MB_ACTIVE, nil,
      TS_TRUE, Size);
  Rect.Create(0, 0, ClientWidth, Size.cy);
  DrawThemeBackground(Theme, Canvas.Handle, MENU_BARBACKGROUND, MB_ACTIVE,
      Rect, nil);
  CloseThemeData(Theme);
end;
```

In a `WM_PAINT` handler this could look like the following.

```
procedure TForm1.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  DC: HDC;
  PS: TPaintStruct;

  Theme: HTHEME;
  Size: TSize;
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  if Message.DC = 0 then
    DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS)
  else
    DC := Message.DC;

  Theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, VSCLASS_MENU);
  GetThemePartSize(Theme, DC, MENU_BARBACKGROUND, MB_ACTIVE, nil,
      TS_TRUE, Size);
  Rect.Create(0, 0, ClientWidth, Size.cy);
  DrawThemeBackground(Theme, DC, MENU_BARBACKGROUND, MB_ACTIVE,
      Rect, nil);
  CloseThemeData(Theme);

  if Message.DC = 0 then begin
    Message.DC := DC;
    inherited;
    EndPaint(Handle, PS);
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: @ Sertac, I am trying to convert the code you posted to straight Windows API.  In the WM_PAINT message , the first statement "Theme := OpenThemeData(Wnd, VSCLASS_MENU);" gives me an access violation. I am not familiar with the theme API, is there something wrong in my "translation" of that statement ?, thank you.

Comment: @Sci - Can't tell without knowing what you're doing. I posted an example.

Comment: @ Sertac, what I'm doing is programming directly to the Windows API as C programmers do (not C++).  IOW, no objects anywhere, just API calls and Window messages processing.  I your statement, "Theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, VSCLASS_MENU);" I _guessed_ that the "Handle" parameter is a window handle (from the MSDN documentation), consequently the statement became "Theme := OpenThemeData(Wnd, VS_CLASS);" the "Wnd" variable I am passing is the handle of the window that received the message.  Therefore that value is valid.  Everything else is the same, yet I get an access violation. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Handle is the window handle alright. The function normally returns 0 when it fails. VSCLASS_MENU is the string 'MENU', MENU_BARBACKGROUND is 7, MB_ACTIVE is 1. OpenThemeData is exported from uxtheme.dll with stdcall convention, accepts a handle and a PWideChar parameter and returns a handle. I suggest you to ask a question providing a reproduction case. Do not edit this one for it's an entirely different matter.

Comment: Sertac, thank you for all the patience and help.  I figured out why I was getting an exception.  Free Pascal has a pointer variable to OpenThemeData which is initialized only if InitThemeLibrary is called (a little detail that won't be in the MSDN documentation).  Now that I know why such a simple function call wasn't working I can focus on the rest of the code you provided.  Unfortunately, I won't be able to dedicate any more time to this problem until tomorrow but, I will provide feedback.  It's the least I can do.  Thank you again.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur If this answer helped you consider accepting it.

Comment: @ Sertac, the code works.  Thank you Sertac.  There is one very unusual thing now, the height returned by GetThemePartSize is different (larger on my installation) than the height returned by GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUSIZE).  I am left wondering why those sizes don't match, it seems they should.  PS: I accepted your answer, your code is correct, it works and I am thankful for your efforts and help.

Comment: @Sci - Thanks and you're welcome. Metric should be accurate, part is just a resource.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur When you are calling GetThemePartSize what is your ˙THEMESIZE˙argument that you pass to the mentioned function? Based on this argument the function could return the minimum size, the size of the component that best matches or the actually drawn size https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/ne-uxtheme-themesize

Comment: @Silver - None of them have got anything to do with actual system metrics, theme parts are just general purpose resources.